# Cloth simulated hair inside of an Armature?

Tags: armature, cloth-simulation

Is it possible to have a cloth simulation inside of an armature?
[image]

The head on the left doesnt have an armature

The head on the right has an armature but now the hair wont simulate.
I think the vertex group that holds the hair to the bone is
messing with the simulation

any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no problem with such setup. Follow this to make sure everything is fine:

1. Mesh is bind to the armature with weight paint:

   [image]

   Here the whole plane is fully weighted to the bone.
2. Create a new vertex group for pinning. Here I pinned 2 corner vertices:

   [image]
3. Use this pinning group for cloth simulation. Also make sure the cloth simulation is after armature deform in modifiers so it takes as input the posed mesh:

   [image]

   [image]
4. Now the simulation works on top of armature as expected:

   [image]

Comment: As simple as moving the modifier up the stack, thxs

Answer (score 1):

Things to start with :

- Remove the armature modifier from the hair.
- Control the hair using constraints ( copy rotation/location from the bone or the head ) you 'll have to change the origins to achieve good results.